# MiKTeX Package Manager not installing new packages

Tags: installing, miktex

I have just started using LaTeX as of last week. I have tried using the MiKTeX 2.9 package manager in order to install new packages (such as `cite` for example). However, whenever I try this I get the following error message:

```
No Data:

Data: Get host by name failed in tcp_connect().
```

Does anyone have any ideas on what is going wrong and what I can do to amend this?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: One possibility is that something on your side blocks the communication e.g. a proxy. In this case you will have to create a local repository on your harddrive and install from there. The other possibility is that 1. one of the repositories or 2. the central server is down. In this case the standard solutions are : 1. Try to change the repository 2. Wait a day.

Comment: Does this problem continue?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it could be solved with different software setting.